# Can LWCs be used in Mobile SDK Hybrid Local Apps?

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobilesdk, lightning-out, hybrid-local

I see that as of v8.2, the [Mobile SDK can use LWCs in Hybrid Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_lightning_web_components.htm). But looking closer, it looks like they can only be used in Hybrid ***Remote*** Apps and note Hybrid ***Local*** apps. Our current app is a hybrid local app because it uses an offine mode and so if we used this, we would need to use the LWC offline. I assume that this would not be possible, correct? Or, is there a possibility here that is not covered by the documentation?